# OpenCV installed successfully BUT ImportError: No module named 'cv2'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

So I have successfully installed `OpenCV 3.2.0` from source on `Ubuntu 14.04` and I get this error:

```
(cv2) mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/opencv-3.2.0/build$  /usr/local/bin/opencv_version
3.2.0
(cv2) mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/opencv-3.2.0/build$ python 
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 17 2016, 01:08:31) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'cv2'
>>> import cv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'cv'
```

What should I have done after `sudo make install` step that I might have missed?

Unfortunately there's no cv2 here as well:

```
mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/opencv-3.2.0/build$ ls /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/
clonevirtualenv.py          numpy                        protobuf-3.1.0.post1.dist-info        stevedore                              virtualenvwrapper
django                      numpy-1.12.0.egg-info        protobuf-3.1.0.post1-py2.7-nspkg.pth  stevedore-1.20.0.dist-info             virtualenvwrapper-4.7.2-py3.4.egg-info
Django-1.10.5.dist-info     olefile                      __pycache__                           tensorflow                             virtualenvwrapper-4.7.2-py3.4-nspkg.pth
easy_install.py             olefile-0.44-py3.4.egg-info  PyYAML-3.12-py3.4.egg-info            tensorflow_gpu-0.12.1.dist-info        wheel
external                    OleFileIO_PL.py              scipy                                 theano                                 wheel-0.29.0.dist-info
google                      pbr                          scipy-0.18.1-py3.4.egg-info           Theano-0.8.2-py3.4.egg-info            yaml
image                       pbr-1.10.0.dist-info         setuptools                            virtualenv-15.1.0.dist-info
image-1.5.5-py3.4.egg-info  PIL                          setuptools-33.1.1.dist-info           virtualenv_clone-0.2.6-py3.4.egg-info
keras                       Pillow-4.0.0-py3.4.egg-info  six-1.10.0.dist-info                  virtualenv.py
Keras-1.2.0-py3.4.egg-info  pkg_resources                six.py                                virtualenv_support
```

Comment: Do you have the `python3-dev` package installed?  When you ran `cmake`, did it say it was going to install python 3 bindings?

Comment: I can't remember about your second question but CMAKE was successfully finished and `$ sudo pip3 install python3-dev
Downloading/unpacking python3-dev
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement python3-dev
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for python3-dev
Storing debug log for failure in /home/mona/.pip/pip.log`

Comment: What if you run `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`?

Comment: nvm I already had it `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-dev is already the newest version.
python3-dev set to manually installed.
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libxine1-bin
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.`

Comment: What happens if you run `python2 -c "import cv2"`?

Comment: `$ python2
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> import cv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cv2.cv import *
ImportError: No module named cv`

Comment: I have specifically installed it for Python 3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133510/discussion-between-amiller27-and-mona-jalal).

Answer (score 1):

I've come across the same problem when installing openCV on Raspberry Pi 3 following this guide:
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/

The issue was that the cv2.so file installed in "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/" instead of "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/".

The solution for me was simply to copy the file with this command:
"sudo cp /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so"

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked in reverse for me; Raspberry Pi 4 64bit build for Python3/3.9 installed into /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages and would not import until I copied cv2 folder it into /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages. Thank you for the troubleshooting tip!

Answer (score 0):

Move the cv2.so file from *dist-packages* to *site-packages* as suggested by Slashy. It worked for me